# How to extract stress within a certain bounding geometry in an Abaqus ODB using scripting?

Tags: scripting, abaqus, finite-element-analysis, odb

I wish to be able to **extract stress (S11)** **and its corresponding element's z-coordinates** only in a **certain bounding cylinder**. My ODB files are relatively big and it would be quite helpful if I could limit the number of elements I have to compute. I need to use scripting and avoid viewport manipulation as I've a large number of ODBs to process.

I have attached a schematic of an example ODB.

[Please click here for a schematic of an example ODB.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJYym.png)

Comment: ideally you would partition the geometry to create an element set containing elements in the target region.

Comment: Hello agentp. Thank you for your response. I'm using an orphan mesh in Abaqus. Using scanIP, a meshing software, to create the mesh for my required resolution.

Comment: Hello,

I am using getByBoundingCylinder -

"myNodes = AllNodes.getByBoundingCylinder(centre1, centre2, radius)"

Would you know how I could convert the array myNodes into a set so that I could use the probe function in Visualization to write S11 and Z coordinates to a file?

Comment: Figured out the sets bit. For an orphan mesh, it needs to take the complete node set from model.instances to create a set.